# execl call weird behaviour

Tags: c, exec, fork

```
  if (fork_return==0)
{
  printf("FROM THE CHILD PROCESS \n");
  //print process id
  printf("The child id is: %d \n", (int) getpid ());
  //parent id
  printf("The parent id is: %d \n", (int) getppid ());
  //group id
  printf ("The group id is: %d \n", (int) getpgrp ());
  printf("\n");

  //call cat function
  execl("/bin/cat","cat",argv[1]);
}
```

So the weird problem I'm having is that the execl call will not do anything when placed at the end of all of these printf calls. However, when I place the execl call above at the top of all of the printf functions it works as expected.

Is there a mistake I'm making in the execl call?

Thanks!

Comment: The last argument to execl should be a pointer to NULL.

Comment: Remember that the `exec` family of function can fail (like almost any other system call), and then *do* return with a return value of `-1`. Do the usual when a system call fails, and print the error.

Comment: yes the problem was I forgot the NULL. thanks john!

Answer (score 0):

Your `execl` needs to have `(char *)NULL` as the last argument

```
execl("/bin/cat", "cat", argv[1], (char *)NULL);
```